# Why/when to use entityManager.remove(...)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wrote the following snippet during a training/course:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void deleteStudent(Integer id) {
 
    //Using entityManager.remove causes two queries, I dunno why/when this is used!
 
    Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, id);
 
    System.out.println("Deleting student with id "+student);
 
    entityManager.remove(student);
 
}
```

As I had suspected, this fires two queries:

```
Hibernate: select s1_0.id,s1_0.email,s1_0.first_name,s1_0.last_name from student s1_0 where s1_0.id=?
Deleting student with id Student{id='5', firstName='Paul', lastName='Dove', email='pault.dove@somemail.com'}
Hibernate: delete from student where id=?
```

If one uses explicit delete query:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void deleteStudentEfficient(Integer id) {
 
    int noOfRowsDeleted = entityManager.createQuery("delete from Student where id = :id").setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
 
    System.out.println("Deleting student with id: "+id+" noOfRowsDeleted: "+noOfRowsDeleted);
 
}
```

only one query is executed:

```
Hibernate: delete from student where id=?
Deleting student with id: 3 noOfRowsDeleted: 1
```

Question:

Why/when to prefer entityManager.remove() to entityManager.createQuery(...).setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate() ?

What am I missing here?

Comment: First, there are several cases in which you have to check conditions before deleting an object, so you have to retrieve the object to check conditions and then decide whether to delete it or not. Secondly, even if hibernate allows you to execute more or less native queries, but you must always interact with the objects of your session so that you will always have a connection between your objects in terms of state (persistance, detached, removed ... ) and cascade operations

Comment: Above comment just needs to add caching to the list. execute Update may (or likely) not remove the deleted entity from JPA managed caches, while em.remove certainly must. If that entity was loaded in a context or second level cache, em.find may(provider and query specific) still return it - this is why JPA suggests bulk queries be done early in a context lifecycle before entities are loaded